# Firebase Realtime Database - Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an app (Ionic Angular Capacitor 2) calling some object in a Firebase realtime database. It have been working fine with access rules and anonymous auth. But after some modules updating (Don't know if thats the problem) i get permission denied when calling the db.
This is happening in both web and on ios/android.
I've read all pages from google and here. But mostly the problem is firestore rules on Realtime db or solved by setting .read/.write rules to true.

This is the auth called on OnInit() when user is created or logged in, continueLoad() is called:

```
async loginAndLoad() {
  // create anonymous user if not exists and/or log in
 await this.fireauth.signInAnonymously().catch((error) => {
     console.log('Login error: ' + error.code);
     console.log('Login error message: ' + error.message);
  });
 // trigger state change, when user is logged in
  this.fireauth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
 
    if (user.isAnonymous) {
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      var uid = user.uid;
      console.log('User added: ' + isAnonymous);
      console.log('User uid: ' + uid);
      // We have a signed in user, go on.. Else throw error
         this.continueLoad();
    } else {
          this.loginAndLoad();
        }
  });
}
```

Example of database call, this i called from this.continueLoad():

```
async getElements() {
     const elements = this.db.list('settings/elements/da/');
     const subscribe = await elements.snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
           subscribe.unsubscribe();
       let array = [];
       res.forEach(child => {
         let a: any;
          a = child.payload.toJSON();
           if (a.status == "published") {
            array.push({key: child.key,title: a.title});
          }
       })
        this.storage.set('elements', JSON.stringify(array));
     })
}
```

This is the Realtime database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "!data.exists()",
    "products": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        ".indexOn": ["stats", "status", "user_warn", "image_approved", "image_added", "note", "description","title","date_published","date_edited","date_added"]
    },
    "searchwords": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"  
    },
    "users": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
    },
    "settings": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
    },
    "routes": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
    },
    "campaigns": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
    }  
  }
}
```

Here is the Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1100.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 11.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 2.4.6
   @capacitor/android : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/core    : 2.4.6
   @capacitor/ios     : 2.4.7

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.13
   OS     : macOS Big Sur
```

This is so frustrating... Hope there is some one with a logic idea of the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the problem. As mentioned in the beginning som plugins were updated. (After trying a new plugin).
So after hours and hours of debugin. I downgraded to Firebase 8.1.2 and @angular/fire to 6.1.5 everything worked again..